# Can I detonate things without losing friends?

Tags: the-sims-3

I have the Sims 3 Ambitions and Late Night expansion packs installed and when I detonate stuff to get scraps and the challenge, I seem to be losing friendship points with all my friends and even family members even though I am detonating my own stuff at home.

This might be related to the fact that I have a 1 start celebrity star and paparazzi sometimes disgrace me using saying I'm vandalizing.

Can I detonate objects without losing friends?

Comment: Another entry in the "best question titles when taken out of context" file.

Comment: @Chad +1 haha exactly.  I follow this question from SO because I really wanted to know the context

Comment: I was actually expecting the "magicka" tag.

Comment: @Bora Magicka rivals TF2 in the "surprisingly gory" category.

Comment: It would not surprise me if this were yet another bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have detonated many of my own objects, but I do have a higher celebrity rating (5).

Maybe if you build your celebrity rating before you try to detonate anything else.

If you still need scrap, you can buy an inventing workshop and buy scrap, or you can go to the dump and scavenge for scrap in the piles of rubbish.

Comment: where do you detonate these? i always do it in the garden, maybe doing it inside would help but one of my sims peed itself in its room and the paparazi still found out.

Comment: I do it inside, but I don't think they actually peed themself, sometimes paparazzi just make stuff up and then your sim has to live with 3 days of public humiliation.

Comment: @Zoe it does say 'false aquisation' on the moddlet then though.

Comment: @Andy so that should have been a one off thing. If you try to detonate again, it probably won't happen.

Comment: @Zoe no i get it every time, even if i still have a moodlet, it just resets timer on it. its also never a false aquisation for my outdoor detonating. would the fact that i blow up multiple things and sometimes fail to blow them all up causing some residue to catch fire be causing these problems?

Comment: @Andy If your objects catch fire, your sim would most likely pee themselves. When they are successfull at detonating do they still pee themselves? And that might explain why your friends have been disliking you because they are embarrassed by you.